# Validate and add new item in database

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to validate whether item exist or not in database. If not exist,then add into database. else return false message

I don't know where I did wrong.

1. Web api to add new itemType

   ```
       public bool AddItemType(_ItemType itemType, int modifiedBy)
     {
       DbInput dbInput = new DbInput();

       dbInput[Column.ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_NAME] = new 
      Cell(itemType.ItemTypeName, DataType.Text);
       dbInput[Column.ItemType.CREATED_USER_ID] = new 
   Cell(itemType.CreatedUserId, DataType.Integer);
       dbInput[Column.ItemType.MODIFIED_BY] = new Cell(modifiedBy, 
      DataType.Integer);
       dbInput[Column.ItemType.MODIFIED_DATE_TIME] = new 
     Cell(DateTime.Now, DataType.Date);
       dbInput[Column.ItemType.DELETED_FLAG] = new Cell(false, 
     DataType.Boolean);

       return InsertRecord(Table.ITEM_TYPE, dbInput) > 0;

   }
   ```
2. Check if item type exist.

   ```
    public bool IsItemTypeExist(string itemTypeName, int itemTypeId)
   {
       DbRecord dbRecord = new DbRecord();
       string condition = String.Format("{0} = {1} AND {2} != {3} AND {4} 
     != {5}", Column.ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_NAME, 
    CastToSQLText(itemTypeName), Column.ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_ID, 
    itemTypeId, Column.ItemType.DELETED_FLAG,
           CastToSQLBoolean(true));

       return QuerySingleRecord(Table.ITEM_TYPE, Column.ALL, condition, 
     ref dbRecord);
     }
   ```
3. Angular to add new item type

   ```
      <div *ngIf="pnlItemType" class="float-right">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" title="Add" 
   (click)="addNewItemType(itemType);"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> 
        </button>
   </div>
   ```
4. modal view of add new item type

   ```
     <ng-template #mdlAddNewItemType>
      <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title"> Add New Item Type </h4>
   <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
     (click)="hideModal();">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="txtAddNewItemType"> New Item Type Name<span 
    class="text-danger">*</span></label>
       <input [(ngModel)] = "itemTypeName" type="text" class="form- 
      control" id="txtAddNewItemType">
     </div>
       </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mg-rt-10" 
     (click)="hideModal();"> Cancel</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
     (click)="createNewItemType();">Save changes</button>
     </div>
    </ng-template>
   ```
5. angular codebehind

   ```
       addNewItemType(itemType:ItemType){
          this.itemType = itemType;
          this.txtAddNewItemType = itemType.ItemTypeName;

          this.openModal(this.mdlAddNewItemType);

       }

         createNewItemType(){
       let itemType =  new ItemType();
          itemType.ItemTypeName = this.txtAddNewItemType;


          this.itemTypeService.createNewItemType(itemType)
         .subscribe(response => {
           if(response.Code == ErrorCode.Success){
          this.hideModal();

          this.viewItemTypeList();
          this.updateMessage(this.MESSAGE_NEW_ITEM_TYPE_ADDED);
            }
          else
          this.errorMessage(response.Message);
        }, error => { this.errorMessage(this.MESSAGE_UNABLE_PROCEED)});
         }
   ```

Expected result is new item type added if not exist in database. If exist in database, return message error code

Answer (score 0):

I had found my mistake.

1. calling addNewItemType function has no parameter.

   ```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" title="Add" 
        (click)="addNewItemType();"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> 
     </button>
   ```
2. inside codebehind of add new item type accept empty string

   ```
    addNewItemType(){
         this.txtAddNewItemType = "";
      this.openModal(this.mdlAddNewItemType);}
   ```
3. should declare txtAddNewItemType variable in codebehind and similar to ngModel for data binding.

   ```
       <input [(ngModel)] = "txtAddNewItemType" type="text" class="form- 
       control" id="txtAddNewItemType">
   ```